# How to extract user that created a tweet returned by api.search in tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to search for tweets containing a specified hashtag, and then get the user that created the tweet.

```
import tweepy

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="python", tweet_mode='extended').items()

while True:
    tweet = next(tweets)
    for hashtag in tweet.entities.get('hashtags'):
        ht = hashtag['text']
        # process the hashtag...

    # who is the user that created this tweet?
    user = ???
```

How do I go about extracting the user from the `tweet` object?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at either the `name` property or `screen_name` property of the `user` object to find out who posted a tweet.

```
print(tweet.user.name)
print(tweet.user.screen_name)
```

For example, my `name` on Twitter is **Bill the Lizard**, but by `screen_name` is [@lizardbill](https://twitter.com/lizardbill).